# change in weight not taking effect in the layout

Tags: android, layout, textview

I think I am missing something basic here. See if any of you can help.

I have an activity(activity_story1) where I am loading some text and some other controls. The way I have laid out all the compoents is by putting them in groups of RelativeLayout within a LinearLayout and then I have assigned weights to those RelativeLayouts. Sample xml below for reference.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Story1Activity" 
android:id="@+id/StoryLinearLayout">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleStory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStory1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerStoryLinearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerStoryRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PageCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="page count"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="addBookmark"
                android:clickable="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am loading some text in the textviews above in onCreate. So far so good.

Now I am overiding onConfigurationChanged() so as when user changes screen alignment my content remains same and onCreate() is not called to reload the contents in textviews. In onConfigurationChanged(), I am also using the code below to change the weight of my relativelayout "titleStoryRelativeLayout".

```
//change the weight of the textview when screen alignment changes
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_story1, null);
   LinearLayout yourRL = (LinearLayout)ll.findViewById(R.id.footerStoryLinearLayout);
   yourRL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.1f));
```

However once I realign my screen(thats when onConfigurationChanged() is being called) the change in weight does not seem to take effect. I can see that the variables yourRL etc are getting populated. 
The basic reason I am changing the weight of my Relativelayout(which holds the titleStory TextView) is becuase when alignment changes i want the height of my titleStory textview to change(increase/decrease) for better viewing. With the code I have put in onConfigurationChanged() above, I was expecting the weight to be changed(from 0.05 to 0.01) and hence the height of the textview also should have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Updated my xml to use LinearLayout(Question updated with the new xml) and then used the code below to update the Weight. I guess I was complicating by defining too many layouts.

```
LinearLayout yourRL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footerStoryLinearLayout);
    yourRL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.5f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this xml file doesn't give error it doesn't mean that you can use these attributes (`weight`, `orientation` and in your case `weight` associated to LinearLayout) with RelativeLayout. Please see the documentation for [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) first. In that you will not find `android:layout_weight` property  where as in [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) you can find that property in documentation of android.

Still if you want to use weight you have to use LinearLayout in RelativeLayout with fill_parrent height and width.

I guess you got me..

Comment: i did some changes to assign the weight to LinearLayout. Still same issues. Here is my new xml now

Comment: Please refer the updated xml/code in my latest edit to the question.

Comment: Solved it...used the code below   Inflator was not needed as I coukld directly get the Lineralyout.........                                     LinearLayout yourRL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footerStoryLinearLayout);
     yourRL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.5f));